# how do i extract the largest number from a string?

Tags: javascript

i used the below code but sometimes I get NaN. please tell me where am I going wrong

```js
var a = "I was born on 12 october 1998.";

var b = a.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '');

b = b.split(' ');

var c = b.map(b => +b);

c = Math.max(...c);

console.log(c);
```

sample input:

```
"I was born on 12 october 1998."
```

sample output:

```
1998
```

Comment: Your code _does_ print `1998`.  Can you show an example where it prints `NaN`?

Comment: `Math.max(..."I was born on 12 october 1998.".match(/\d+/g).map(Number))`

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Answer (score 4):

You're replacing alphabetical characters with the empty string, but not any other non-digit characters. For example, `,` will not be replaced, resulting in `NaN` when converted to a number:

```js
var a = 'hi 1234,';

var b = a.replace(/[a-z]/gi, '');

b = b.split(' ');

var c = b.map(b => +b);

c = Math.max(...c);

console.log(c);
```

Use `.match(/\d+/g)` instead, to match numbers:

```js
var a = 'hi 1234,';
const nums = a.match(/\d+/g);
console.log(Math.max(...(nums || [])));
```

Comment: so i was thinking why do we have the OR operator and [ ] in the last line but I could not figure out. Help please @CertainPerformance

Comment: A global regular expression with `.match` will return `null` instead of the empty array when no matches are found. The `|| []` ensures that no error is thrown when spread into `Math.max`.